# Powershell script - Organize script by functions

Tags: powershell-2.0

When I put the Function `{}` around my powershell script, to change the registry key, the script doesn't seem to run within the brackets.  When I take out the Function {}, the script runs fine.  What am I missing here?

```
Function ClearPageFile   
{
  $regpath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM....(rest of path)"
  $key = "ClearPageFileAtShutdown
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name $key -Value 0
}
```

Comment: `Function` just create (not execute) function.

Comment: How can I execute the function?  I have about ten that i'll have one after the other.

Comment: How you call your function in your script? What happens when you call "ClearePageFile"?

Comment: That is what I'm not sure how to do.  If I have several functions like that in one script, how can i set up the script to run all of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are calling the function some place else, here's your answer...

```
Function ClearPageFile   
{
  $regpath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM....(rest of path)"
  $key = "ClearPageFileAtShutdown
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name $key -Value 0
}

#call the function
ClearPageFile
```